# How much tolerance is there for a frameless glass shower door?

Tags: doors, shower, glass

I did a shower remodel that involved moving a wall and re-tiling my shower. The new width for the door opening is 33.5 inches. I see pre-made frameless glass shower doors that are listed as being acceptable for 33" openings. Do frameless glass shower doors have enough tolerance to make this work?

Comment: I think there are wider doors, as well as the narrower, out there. Just watch out for the requirement on opening width.

Comment: It depends on the hardware, different manufacturers and brands are different. Some have a good bit of adjustment to allow installation in openings that are not square. The hardware used and the glass thickness affect the maximum width that a single pivoting panel can be, hence wider openings commonly have a fixed side panel ("side lite"). Also, many high-end units can be custom made for you...

Comment: The track on each side can be shimmed .25 inch  then caulked.

Answer (score 1):

The maker of the door will give you the max and minimum opening it will fit in.

Off the shelf shower doors, so they will fit varying sizes of showers will make up the difference by the lap/overhang of the glass on the hinge side of the door. This will only allow the door to open out, which is code. If the door is custom made, it would be possible to have it swing in and out.

Typically the biggest concern is the plumb of the walls and level of the curb. The caulk that seals the glass can only fill up so big a gap.